# Transformar valores positivos em negativos em uma data.frame baseado em uma condição em outra coluna (R)

Tags: r, condição

Eu tenho o seguinte data.frame ::

```
df <- data.frame(Qtd=c(100,200,300,400,500),
             op=c('V','C','C','V','V'), stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Como eu consigo transformar os valores na coluna Qtd para negativo se o valor da coluna op for V ??

Tentei esse comando mas deu erro :

```
Teste <- within(df, Qtd[op == 'V'] <- -Qtd[])

Warning message:
 In Qtd[op == "V"] <- -Qtd[] :
 number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seu código também funcionaria normalmente, o que faltou você fazer foi colocar a mesma condição lógica dentro de `-Qtd[]`. Corrigindo:

```
within(df, Qtd[op == 'V'] <- -Qtd[op == 'V'])
   Qtd op
1 -100  V
2  200  C
3  300  C
4 -400  V
5 -500  V
```

Answer (score 5):

O `ifelse` pode te ajudar aqui:

```
df <- data.frame(Qtd=c(100,200,300,400,500),
                 op=c('V','C','C','V','V'), stringsAsFactors=F)
df$Qtd <- ifelse(df$op == "V", -df$Qtd, df$Qtd)
```

Ou você também pode usar o `which` para primeiro filtrar as linhas, e depois aplicar a operação:

```
df <- data.frame(Qtd=c(100,200,300,400,500),
                 op=c('V','C','C','V','V'), stringsAsFactors=F)
rows <- which(df$op == "V")
df$Qtd[rows] = -df$Qtd[rows]
```

Comment: Acho que o uso do `which` é redundante, não tem porque fazer a detecção dos índices da condição se os próprios valores de TRUE/FALSE são suficientes pra fazer o subseting e mudar apenas os valores V. A segunda opção pode ser simplesmente `df$Qtd[df$op == "V"] <- -df$Qtd[df$op == "V"]`